# Modificar un campo de un documento de mongodb con mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo un esquema de un libro en mongodb y estoy tratando de insertar un archivo pdf con las imágenes de los capítulos

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0f9a5602403b1dc8d97547"),
    "genders" : [ 
        "genero1, genero2, genero3"
    ],
    "date" : ISODate("2020-07-16T00:07:50.380Z"),
    "chapters" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0f9a9a02403b1dc8d97548"),
            "numcap" : "1",
            "titlecap" : "empieza",
            "imgpage" : "",
            "datechapter" : ISODate("2020-07-16T00:08:58.108Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f0f9b276460791ef0b57844"),
            "numcap" : "2",
            "titlecap" : "segundo titulo cap",
            "imgpage" : "",
            "datechapter" : ISODate("2020-07-16T00:11:19.629Z")
        }
    ],
    "title" : "Titulo libro prueba3",
    "description" : "descripcion del libro prueba3",
    "image" : "file0-1594858112936.jpg",
    "type" : "tipo del libro3",
    "state" : "estado2",
    "autor" : ObjectId("5f0f50c64fdb463dbc1520e9"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Quisiera saber cómo modificar el campo **imgpage** que se encuentra vacío, este es mi controller:

```
uploadPages: (req, res) => {

    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(404).send({
        status: 'error',
        message: 'Imagen no subida...'
      });
    }

    const file_name = req.file.filename;
    const file_path = req.file.path;
    const original_name = req.file.originalname;
    const name_split = original_name.split('.');
    const img_extens = name_split[1];

    if (img_extens != 'pdf') {
      fs.unlink(file_path, (err) => {
        return res.status(404).send({
          status: 'error',
          message: 'formato de archivo a subir no valido....',
          format: img_extens
        });
      });
    }else{

      const articleId = req.params.id; //tomo el id del capitulo

      let update = {
        $set: {
          imgpage: file_name
        }
      };

      articleModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: articleId}, update, {new:true}, (err, chapterUpdated)=>{
        if (err || !chapterUpdated) {
          fs.unlink(file_path, ()=>{
            return res.status(404).send({
              status: 'error',
              message: 'No se ha podido guardar el archivo',
              chapterUpdated
            });
          });
          
        }else{
          return res.status(200).send({
            status: 'success',
            article: chapterUpdated
          });
        }
      });
            
    }
  },
```

he tenido problemas ya que al realizar la función findOneAndUpdate en el callback me arroja vacío **chapterUpdated**, estoy tomando el id del capítulo para modificar, no el del libro como tal, no sé si estoy haciendo bien en dejar que cada capítulo tenga su id.

Este es un proyecto personal que estoy realizando para afianzar mis conocimientos y posteriormente culminarlo y publicarlo. Agradezco mucho quien me pueda enseñar una solución, muchas gracias.

Comment: El documento que muestras de ejemplo no se corresponde con el código que estás trabajando. ¿Podrías indicar si `article` es una colección que contiene los documentos de los capítulos? Si este fuera el caso, ¿el campo `chapters` que muestras en tu documento es una lista de referencias desde una colección a otra? Saludos

Comment: ¿podrías añadir el Schema de la colección articleModel? Saludos